# Hibernate mapping stops work from time to time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am writing server app and use tomcat, gradle and hibernate/spring to map some entities with mysql database. Each time I start tomcat the app works for some period of time (up to 5 days), but then begins to throw exception on every sql query until I restart the tomcat again. Here is the exception stack, which is always the same:

```
could not extract ResultSet
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1682)
org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
```

Here is the part of my xml config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task           http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="entertainment.service" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mmd?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="plannidev" />

    <!--Configuration-->
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="validationQueryTimeout" value="60" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60" />

    <property name="initialSize" value="8" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="0" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />

    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="28800000" /> <!--8 hours-->
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />

</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean ">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
           <!-- my entity classes --> 
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
            <prop key="connection.pool_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
               class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- my beans here-->

</beans>
```

Property `<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>` is commented because I manually created mysql scheme and use liquibase tool for pathcing the db.

Here is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
compile 'com.factual:factual-java-driver:1.8.8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
compile 'de.u-mass:lastfm-java:0.1.2'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.19'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.8.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
compile 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.2.1.Final'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.19'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:1.19'

compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
compile 'com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:1.19'
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.35'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time-hibernate:1.3'
compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA'
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.javadocmd:simplelatlng:1.3.1'
compile 'com.intersult:jpa-fix:1.1'

compile 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'
compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:4.1.2'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:4.4.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
compile 'org.json:json:20160212'

compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.3.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.1.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.1.RELEASE'

compile 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.0.3'
compile 'org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:3.1.0-M05'

compile 'com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-spring:1.8'

compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'

compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'

compile 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.5.1'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.26'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'
compile 'com.restfb:restfb:1.30.0'

compile group: 'com.github.davidmoten', name: 'geo', version: '0.7.1'
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.6.10'
compile group: 'org.springframework.retry', name: 'spring-retry', version: '1.1.2.RELEASE'

providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
providedCompile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jsp-api:7.0.55'

testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5"

}
```

Unfortunately I have a lot of entities classes to post it code here. Maybe somebody could help me whether it is everything OK with my configuration? Or maybe somebody faced with similar problems? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: may yuo post the full stacktrace? and the query causing the error?

Comment: Each sql query ends with this same stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting this error because hibernate can't map values from db to your model, it could happen when u are trying binding string column to int property in your entity or bind not valid enum value etc.

Try to run hibernate with hbm2dll **validate** value

Comment: I found that some columns that are marked as foreign keys in auto created schema (if I set *<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>*) are not marked so in my manually created schema, could it be the reason?

Comment: I don't think so,
You will get exception when entity referred by your foreign key does not exist , but it will be EntityNotFoundException

Comment: You didn't get any exception while u ran hibernate with hbm2dll in validate mode ?

Comment: No, everything was fine. I have added this foreign keys constraints, after that, it's running 1.5 days without such exceptions. But it already worked a couple of days, but then began to throw exceptions again. Will see futher, hope it will help